# The screw inserts in my iiyama monitor are stripped. What to do?

Tags: display

Apologies if this is not the correct place for this, but I have an iiyama monitor, and the mounting screw inserts appear to have stripped. The screws just spin and spin in either direction but never loosen. Is there a way to fix this? Here's a link to a photo:

[image]

The bottom left screw is not stuck but the others are.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you posted the wrong image...

Comment: @wysiwyg You are correct, apologies! Should be fixed now. :D

Comment: Huh... somebody got a little overzealous well tightening those down I guess. Usually pretty easy, get some pressure underneath of it to lift well unscrewing them, use a scissors, needle nose pliers, side cutters, wire snips, etc. and put it under the head of the bolt to apply pressure to lift it while turning it out. Hopefully it is just the bolt threads that are borked, otherwise this monitor is probably junk without it's regular desk stand.

Comment: I would take it to a tooler who can help you remove the bolts.

Comment: It depends on what's stripped.  If it's the threads, you would likely be able to pull the screws out.  If the screws are firm but turn freely, the threaded inserts may no longer be securely held, and they could be what is spinning.  You may need to open the case and solve it from the inside.  If necessary, you can cut or drill off the bolt heads to get the mount off.  Removing the screws may be only step one.  To be able to mount it again, you might need to do some mechanical modifications as some of the ways things are built can't be properly repaired or replicated with home tools.